# Passing a variable from a thread to a separate arraylist

Tags: java, class, variables

I am very new to java and haven't learnt much at the moment but I have a issue.

I am trying to pass a variable that runs in a thread to another java class.

in the client thread I am running:

```
UserReg UR = new UserReg();
UR.addUser(userID);
```

and in the separate java class I have got:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserReg {

    ArrayList userList = new ArrayList();

    void addUser (String UserID) {   
        userList.add(UserID);
        System.out.println(userList);  
    }  
}
```

the issue I have is that each time a new thread runs then it overwrites the array list and doesn't add to it.

Comment: No multithreading shown. The title (or question body) should also be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because it has got do with this:

```
UserReg UR = new UserReg();
UR.addUser(userID);
```

Each time, it initializes the `userReg` and hence the `ArrayList` inside.

What you can probably do is that (temporarily but not a decent solution) would to make the `userList` static